# IOS drawing text inside a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c

im trying to draw a text on a subview, the view appearing fine but the text not, this is what im doing, the view have black color, the text have white color, text and rect value given in other method:

```
NSString* sumText = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%0.1f",sum];
CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(chartLocation.x+chartLength+10,
                              chartLocation.y,
                              20,
                              20);
[self drawTextRect:sumText inRect:textRect];


-(void)drawTextRect:(NSString *)sumText inRect:(CGRect)textRect {
UIFont* font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:(20/2)];
UIColor* textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle]mutableCopy];
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
NSDictionary* stringAttr=@{NSFontAttributeName:font,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:textColor,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle};
UIView* textView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:textRect];
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[sumText drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:stringAttr];
[self.view addSubview:textView];}
```

am i do anything wrong? thanks

Comment: try setting the backgroundColor (on textView) to [UIColor clearColor] rather than black and I think you'll see the text.. Why don't you use UILabel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is another way you can achieve what you want .

```
UILabel* lblText = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200)];
lblText.text = @"Hello World!";
lblText.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lblText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:lblText];
```

And Output is:

[image: Output]

Comment: thanks! i should have do this from first place instead of finding in google XD it points me to drawing text in a view....

Answer (score 1):

The `drawInRect:withAttributes:` method draws the string in the **current graphics context**. You have not defined a context, so your drawing goes nowhere.

If you want to draw the string yourself, you should subclass `UIView`, add the required properties (`sumText`), and overwrite `drawRect:`. A graphics context is automatically created for you in `drawRect:` so you can just go ahead and draw.

But really, you probably just want to use a `UILabel` instead.

Comment: thanks, i don't use UIlabel because what i trying to draw is a value of a chart bar, its always change so i have to draw... :D im still a newbie in ios dev